# Factors affecting the migration of MS SQL into MySQL vice versa

Tags: sql-server, mysql, files

What are the factors affecting the migration of database from MS SQL Server to MySQL causing corrupted files?

I transferred my database from MS SQL Server 2012 into MySQL on the same Windows PC. I used the default migration wizard and it proceed. But when I export one of the media file to my local disk, I cannot open it and it prompt that the file is corrupted.

Comment: Add more details, please.

Comment: For example, I migrated my database from MS SQL Server 2012 into MySQL. It proceed and finished the migration, but ending up on corrupted files, specially the BLOB. Are there any factors to be considered on migrating into different platform?

Comment: Corrupted schema syntax?  Corrupted data?  What kind of corruption?  Sample of the data (before and after)?  How did you do the migration?  Windows versus Unix versus Mac?  Which direction?  CRLF versus LF vs CR?

Comment: As currently asked, your question appears too broad. So, whatever details you are adding to it, please do so using the [edit] link rather than in comments, thanks.

Comment: @RickJames: I'm not sure but as the OP is asking for factors to consider (rather than for a solution to a specific corruption issue), some of the points you are asking about may actually be part of the answer.

Comment: I just updated it. Sorry for the vague description. I am not totally literate about this. I'm just a student.

Comment: One big lesson to learn as a student is how to clearly ask questions.

Comment: "default migration wizard" -- provided by MS SQL?  By MySQL Workbench?  Something else?  What options?  How many tables?

Comment: Character set issues?  In what way is the corruption visible to you?  Bad characters?  Unreadable files?  Bad permissions?  Something else?

Comment: Sit down and imagine what my next flood of questions will be.  Then preemptively answer them.

Comment: Yup, the one from MS SQL. It has 17 tables in total, including the composite PKs table. It's just a small profiling system, but I am using blob for the videos/music/pics for the user. And when I migrated the whole thing, some files were corrupted. The windows says: "The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable."